# I am trying to install Vapor on my raspberrypi but getting strange errors

Tags: swift, raspbian, vapor

I am running Raspbian and have so far installed Swift 5.1.5 and cloned Vapor Branch 18.0.0 beta 27.  I can't seem to get version 5.2 of Swift installed on my system somehow.

Nonetheless, the next step is to build Vapor, but it gives me the following error:

`sudo swift build -c release`

```
Updating https://github.com/jpsim/Yams.git
Updating https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git
Updating https://github.com/vapor/console-kit.git
Updating https://github.com/apple/swift-log.git
Updating https://github.com/tanner0101/mustache.git
https://github.com/apple/swift-nio.git @ master: error: terminated(128): git -C /home/pi/Downloads/toolbox/.build/repositories/swift-nio-b68c973e rev-parse --verify 'master^{commit}' output:
    fatal: Needed a single revision
```

Not sure where to go from there, can't find any relevant info online.

Answer (score 3):

Vapor 4 and the new toolbox all require Swift 5.2 - you'll need to get the installed before anything else.

Next that's an old version of the toolbox, you can find the latest release at https://github.com/vapor/toolbox/releases

Finally, the chances are you don't need the toolbox. It's used for creating new projects. If you just want to build or run existing ones, just use the swift commands

Comment: So I actually had to install ubuntu 20.04 LTS, thank you :)